# I can access Raspberry hostname via browser but I can't access it using Android devices

Tags: server, web

[image: WebAccess]

The title says it all. As you can see in screenshot I can successfully access apache using hostname I tried in in different computer same result. But when i use my mobile phone it says "site can't be reached." I tried pinging it in my phone but no luck. Please can u help me whats the problem here?

Comment: Is your Android device on the same network as your Raspberry Pi and computer?

Comment: Yes Sir.. just same network

Comment: Is your phone able to access RPi via IP address?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal yes i can access Apache using IP address but i want to access it using hostname..

Comment: I just tried it with my phone and RPi and it is accessible. In your mobile browser type `http://pisowifi` in address. It does Google search if you do not put `http`

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Yes i did type http://pisowifi on my phone. my question is why i can't ping it using my phone.. And how did u make it?

Comment: I did nothing special, if you can access RPi on PC via hostname than no problem on RPi side. Have you tried using another phone?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Yes. Same result with others

Comment: Android doesn't support http://raspberrypi.local or http://raspberrypi. You MUST use the IP address http://192.168.3.14 (or wherever your Pi appears on your network).

Comment: there are all kinds of discovery annoyances even on pcs; i remember once having to add a bonjour service or something for windows to find it.  a router setup was just easier for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have to access via hostname you have to edit your host file on android  so that it can know the hostname and redirect to the IP address of Pi

Add a line in `hosts` file with

```
IP-address-of-Pi    hostname(name by which you want to access pi)
```

I think to edit hosts file your device should be rooted

here are few links which might help 
http://www.trishtech.com/2014/08/edit-hosts-file-in-android/ 
https://www.theandroidportal.com/edit-modify-hosts-file-block-websites-android-root/
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this is not applicable if the users phone is not rooted. my aim is to connect on Apache without using a IP address but the hostname. I checked all possibilities but  i dont why i cant connect on my android even if i can see him in network

Comment: I think it's because the systems or servers on network or internet are fundamentally identified by IP address (since we cant remember IP address DNS comes into the picture so that it can redirect to the IP address mapped to the name.)  When you try to connect to Pi on the phone if it says This site can’t be reached and server DNS address could not be found or ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. It most probably could be fixed by above method (editing the host file).  To my knowledge, I think it could be done only if the phone is rooted because we are editing the internal files.

Comment: Not a good method.. i think, but thanks for the @Sneha